# Following up on questions that first appeared in forum.civicrm.org

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I see a thread in the old forum.civicrm.org forum that may need follow-up but that site is now being deprecated. What is the best way to continue the discussion?

For example, I have a proposed solution to the issue discussed in

http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,28816.msg123470.html#msg123470

Comment: I think this question should be moved to meta.

Comment: @Vietyank, thanks for asking - this is a useful question. However it does belong on Meta because the subject is civicrm.stackexchange.com rather than CiviCRM itself. We'll hopefully move it there, which will preserve the question and replies.

Comment: @Coleman, I've voted to move this to Meta. You can do similarly ("close => off-topic => another site") - you have much more SE rep so you might be able to make it happen :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a really good question that I've thought about myself.

I've answered with a stock, "This is a great question!  However, this forum is no longer used for questions.  Please post the question at http://civicrm.stackexchange.com where it will receive a lot more attention."

I'd consider reposting the question yourself for them and giving them a link - but it's better if they post the question, because they'll reap the reputation, which is better for the health of the site and their continued involvement.